# How to download files with very long URLs?

Tags: windows, download

I try to download JSON files and fail with all download tools I tried (WinHTTrack and so on...).

The problem is: file urls are very long, about 4k characters, no tool seems to be able to work with such url length. Google limitation is around 2k.

What could be a workaround to download such files?

URL shortening I tried too: no url shortener was able to shorten such url.

**ps**:

- an URL I try to download looks like [this](https://www.jomashop.com/graphql?query=query%20productDetail(%24urlKey%3AString%2C%24onServer%3ABoolean!)%7BproductDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A%7Burl_key%3A%7Beq%3A%24urlKey%7D%7D)%7Bitems%7B__typename%20id%20sku%20name%20name_wout_brand%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20is_preowned%20brand_name%20brand_url%20manufacturer%20url_key%20stock_status%20out_of_stock_template%20out_of_stock_template_text%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20image%7Blabel%20url%20__typename%7Dupc_code%20item_variation%20media_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dbreadcrumbs%7Bpath%20categories%7Bname%20url_key%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dreview_details%7Breview_summary%20review_count%20__typename%7Drating_configurations%7Brating_attributes%20__typename%7Dshort_description%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Ddescription%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20more_details%7Bgroup_id%20group_label%20group_attributes%7Battribute_id%20attribute_label%20attribute_value%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmsrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dcategories%7Bbreadcrumbs%7Bcategory_id%20category_name%20__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GroupedProduct%7Bitems%7Bqty%20position%20product%7Bid%20sku%20stock_status%20name%20brand_name%20name_wout_brand%20manufacturer%20manufacturer_text%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_availability%20url_key%20is_preowned%20preowned_item_condition%20preowned_item_condition_text%20preowned_box%20preowned_papers%20preowned_papers_year%20preowned_condition_description%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20msrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20ConfigurableProduct%7Bconfigurable_options%7Battribute_code%20attribute_id%20id%20label%20values%7Bdefault_label%20label%20store_label%20use_default_value%20value_index%20swatch_data%7Btype%20value...%20on%20ImageSwatchData%7Bthumbnail%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dvariants%7Battributes%7Bcode%20value_index%20label%20__typename%7Dproduct%7Bid%20brand_name%20brand_url%20brand_size%20manufacturer%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20name_wout_brand%20msrp%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20is_preowned%20model_id%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dsku%20stock_status%20moredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GiftCardProduct%7Ballow_open_amount%20open_amount_min%20open_amount_max%20giftcard_type%20is_redeemable%20lifetime%20allow_message%20message_max_length%20giftcard_amounts%7Bvalue_id%20website_id%20website_value%20attribute_id%20value%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmeta_title%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_keyword%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_description%40include(if%3A%24onServer)canonical_url%40include(if%3A%24onServer)%7D__typename%7D%7D&operationName=productDetail&variables=%7B%22urlKey%22%3A%22raymond-weil-watch-7730-stc-65112%22%2C%22onServer%22%3Atrue%7D).
- An answer from WGet I tried to use looks like:

  ```
    ---request begin---
    GET /graphql?query=query%20productDetail(%24urlKey%3AString%2C%24onServer%3ABoolean!)%7BproductDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A%7Burl_key%3A%7Beq%3A%24urlKey%7D%7D)%7Bitems%7B__typename%20id%20sku%20name%20name_wout_brand%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20is_preowned%20brand_name%20brand_url%20manufacturer%20url_key%20stock_status%20out_of_stock_template%20out_of_stock_template_text%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20image%7Blabel%20url%20__typename%7Dupc_code%20item_variation%20media_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dbreadcrumbs%7Bpath%20categories%7Bname%20url_key%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dreview_details%7Breview_summary%20review_count%20__typename%7Drating_configurations%7Brating_attributes%20__typename%7Dshort_description%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Ddescription%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20more_details%7Bgroup_id%20group_label%20group_attributes%7Battribute_id%20attribute_label%20attribute_value%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmsrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dcategories%7Bbreadcrumbs%7Bcategory_id%20category_name%20__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GroupedProduct%7Bitems%7Bqty%20position%20product%7Bid%20sku%20stock_status%20name%20brand_name%20name_wout_brand%20manufacturer%20manufacturer_text%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_availability%20url_key%20is_preowned%20preowned_item_condition%20preowned_item_condition_text%20preowned_box%20preowned_papers%20preowned_papers_year%20preowned_condition_description%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20msrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20ConfigurableProduct%7Bconfigurable_options%7Battribute_code%20attribute_id%20id%20label%20values%7Bdefault_label%20label%20store_label%20use_default_value%20value_index%20swatch_data%7Btype%20value...%20on%20ImageSwatchData%7Bthumbnail%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dvariants%7Battributes%7Bcode%20value_index%20label%20__typename%7Dproduct%7Bid%20brand_name%20brand_url%20brand_size%20manufacturer%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20name_wout_brand%20msrp%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20is_preowned%20model_id%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dsku%20stock_status%20moredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GiftCardProduct%7Ballow_open_amount%20open_amount_min%20open_amount_max%20giftcard_type%20is_redeemable%20lifetime%20allow_message%20message_max_length%20giftcard_amounts%7Bvalue_id%20website_id%20website_value%20attribute_id%20value%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmeta_title%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_keyword%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_description%40include(if%3A%24onServer)canonical_url%40include(if%3A%24onServer)%7D__typename%7D%7D&operationName=productDetail&variables=%7B%22urlKey%22%3A%22raymond-weil-watch-7730-stc-65112%22%2C%22onServer%22%3Atrue%7D HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent: Wget/1.21.1
    Accept: */*
    Accept-Encoding: identity
    Host: www.jomashop.com
    Connection: Keep-Alive

    ---request end---
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
    ---response begin---
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    Date: Sun, 13 Jun 2021 18:08:53 GMT
    Content-Type: application/json
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    Connection: keep-alive
    CF-Ray: 65ed444b78aa2bd6-FRA
    Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
    Expires: -1
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
    cf-request-id: 0aa829032900002bd6d2af7000000001
    Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
    Pragma: no-cache
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=4869eeab9dbfe8c9ee32cdb28717105373105b26-1623607733-1800-AdcZOtzt129uH6bUp4GVNVqad3bFfj1wNOaoyVb3lYJ21ejdcbH3x4BSznjiPpyX4cJj5WpjoVvm7ys5yd3y+MH/jScid6FAhGgMGVuwwt3u; path=/; expires=Sun, 13-Jun-21 18:38:53 GMT; domain=.jomashop.com; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
    Server: cloudflare
    alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=86400, h3-28=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400, h3=":443"; ma=86400

    ---response end---
    200 OK
    cdm: 1

    Stored cookie jomashop.com -1 (ANY) / <permanent> <secure> [expiry 2021-06-13 20:38:53] __cf_bm 4869eeab9dbfe8c9ee32cdb28717105373105b26-1623607733-1800-AdcZOtzt129uH6bUp4GVNVqad3bFfj1wNOaoyVb3lYJ21ejdcbH3x4BSznjiPpyX4cJj5WpjoVvm7ys5yd3y+MH/jScid6FAhGgMGVuwwt3u
    Registered socket 3 for persistent reuse.
    Length: unspecified [application/json]
    graphql@query=query productDetail($urlKey%3AString,$onServer%3ABoolean!){productDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A{url_key%3A{eq%3A$urlKey}}){items{__typename id sku name name_wout_brand on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority is_preowned brand_na: No such file or directory
    Disabling further reuse of socket 3.
    Closed 3/SSL 0x000000001094c020

    Cannot write to 'graphql@query=query productDetail($urlKey%3AString,$onServer%3ABoolean!){productDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A{url_key%3A{eq%3A$urlKey}}){items{__typename id sku name name_wout_brand on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority is_preowned brand_na' (Bad file descriptor).
    converted 'https://www.jomashop.com/graphql?query=query%20productDetail(%24urlKey%3AString%2C%24onServer%3ABoolean!)%7BproductDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A%7Burl_key%3A%7Beq%3A%24urlKey%7D%7D)%7Bitems%7B__typename%20id%20sku%20name%20name_wout_brand%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20is_preowned%20brand_name%20brand_url%20manufacturer%20url_key%20stock_status%20out_of_stock_template%20out_of_stock_template_text%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20image%7Blabel%20url%20__typename%7Dupc_code%20item_variation%20media_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dbreadcrumbs%7Bpath%20categories%7Bname%20url_key%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dreview_details%7Breview_summary%20review_count%20__typename%7Drating_configurations%7Brating_attributes%20__typename%7Dshort_description%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Ddescription%7Bhtml%20__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20more_details%7Bgroup_id%20group_label%20group_attributes%7Battribute_id%20attribute_label%20attribute_value%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmsrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dcategories%7Bbreadcrumbs%7Bcategory_id%20category_name%20__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GroupedProduct%7Bitems%7Bqty%20position%20product%7Bid%20sku%20stock_status%20name%20brand_name%20name_wout_brand%20manufacturer%20manufacturer_text%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_availability%20url_key%20is_preowned%20preowned_item_condition%20preowned_item_condition_text%20preowned_box%20preowned_papers%20preowned_papers_year%20preowned_condition_description%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20shipping_question_mark_note%20model_id%20msrp%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmoredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20ConfigurableProduct%7Bconfigurable_options%7Battribute_code%20attribute_id%20id%20label%20values%7Bdefault_label%20label%20store_label%20use_default_value%20value_index%20swatch_data%7Btype%20value...%20on%20ImageSwatchData%7Bthumbnail%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dvariants%7Battributes%7Bcode%20value_index%20label%20__typename%7Dproduct%7Bid%20brand_name%20brand_url%20brand_size%20manufacturer%20shipping_availability%20is_shipping_free_message%20shipping_question_mark_note%20name_wout_brand%20msrp%20price_promo_text%20promotext_code%20promotext_type%20promotext_value%20is_preowned%20model_id%20on_hand_priority_text%20on_hand_priority%20price_range%7Bminimum_price%7Bregular_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dfinal_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Dprice_promo_text%20msrp_price%7Bvalue%20currency%20__typename%7Ddiscount_on_msrp%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7Ddiscount%7Bamount_off%20percent_off%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7Dmedia_gallery%7B...%20on%20ProductImage%7Blabel%20role%20url%20sizes%7Bimage_id%20url%20__typename%7Durl_nocache%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dsku%20stock_status%20moredetails%7Bdescription%20__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D__typename%7D...%20on%20GiftCardProduct%7Ballow_open_amount%20open_amount_min%20open_amount_max%20giftcard_type%20is_redeemable%20lifetime%20allow_message%20message_max_length%20giftcard_amounts%7Bvalue_id%20website_id%20website_value%20attribute_id%20value%20__typename%7D__typename%7Dmeta_title%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_keyword%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_description%40include(if%3A%24onServer)canonical_url%40include(if%3A%24onServer)%7D__typename%7D%7D&operationName=productDetail&variables=%7B%22urlKey%22%3A%22raymond-weil-watch-7730-stc-jhdx1%22%2C%22onServer%22%3Atrue%7D' (CP1252) -> 'https://www.jomashop.com/graphql?query=query productDetail(%24urlKey%3AString%2C%24onServer%3ABoolean!){productDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A{url_key%3A{eq%3A%24urlKey}}){items{__typename id sku name name_wout_brand on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority is_preowned brand_name brand_url manufacturer url_key stock_status out_of_stock_template out_of_stock_template_text price_promo_text promotext_code promotext_type promotext_value shipping_availability is_shipping_free_message shipping_question_mark_note model_id image{label url __typename}upc_code item_variation media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}breadcrumbs{path categories{name url_key __typename}__typename}review_details{review_summary review_count __typename}rating_configurations{rating_attributes __typename}short_description{html __typename}description{html __typename}moredetails{description more_details{group_id group_label group_attributes{attribute_id attribute_label attribute_value __typename}__typename}__typename}msrp price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}categories{breadcrumbs{category_id category_name __typename}__typename}... on GroupedProduct{items{qty position product{id sku stock_status name brand_name name_wout_brand manufacturer manufacturer_text is_shipping_free_message shipping_availability url_key is_preowned preowned_item_condition preowned_item_condition_text preowned_box preowned_papers preowned_papers_year preowned_condition_description on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority shipping_question_mark_note model_id msrp price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}moredetails{description __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}... on ConfigurableProduct{configurable_options{attribute_code attribute_id id label values{default_label label store_label use_default_value value_index swatch_data{type value... on ImageSwatchData{thumbnail __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}variants{attributes{code value_index label __typename}product{id brand_name brand_url brand_size manufacturer shipping_availability is_shipping_free_message shipping_question_mark_note name_wout_brand msrp price_promo_text promotext_code promotext_type promotext_value is_preowned model_id on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}sku stock_status moredetails{description __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}... on GiftCardProduct{allow_open_amount open_amount_min open_amount_max giftcard_type is_redeemable lifetime allow_message message_max_length giftcard_amounts{value_id website_id website_value attribute_id value __typename}__typename}meta_title%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_keyword%40include(if%3A%24onServer)meta_description%40include(if%3A%24onServer)canonical_url%40include(if%3A%24onServer)}__typename}}&operationName=productDetail&variables={"urlKey"%3A"raymond-weil-watch-7730-stc-jhdx1"%2C"onServer"%3Atrue}' (UTF-8)
    Converted file name 'graphql@query=query productDetail($urlKey%3AString,$onServer%3ABoolean!){productDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A{url_key%3A{eq%3A$urlKey}}){items{__typename id sku name name_wout_brand on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority is_preowned brand_name brand_url manufacturer url_key stock_status out_of_stock_template out_of_stock_template_text price_promo_text promotext_code promotext_type promotext_value shipping_availability is_shipping_free_message shipping_question_mark_note model_id image{label url __typename}upc_code item_variation media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}breadcrumbs{path categories{name url_key __typename}__typename}review_details{review_summary review_count __typename}rating_configurations{rating_attributes __typename}short_description{html __typename}description{html __typename}moredetails{description more_details{group_id group_label group_attributes{attribute_id attribute_label attribute_value __typename}__typename}__typename}msrp price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}categories{breadcrumbs{category_id category_name __typename}__typename}... on GroupedProduct{items{qty position product{id sku stock_status name brand_name name_wout_brand manufacturer manufacturer_text is_shipping_free_message shipping_availability url_key is_preowned preowned_item_condition preowned_item_condition_text preowned_box preowned_papers preowned_papers_year preowned_condition_description on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority shipping_question_mark_note model_id msrp price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}moredetails{description __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}... on ConfigurableProduct{configurable_options{attribute_code attribute_id id label values{default_label label store_label use_default_value value_index swatch_data{type value... on ImageSwatchData{thumbnail __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}variants{attributes{code value_index label __typename}product{id brand_name brand_url brand_size manufacturer shipping_availability is_shipping_free_message shipping_question_mark_note name_wout_brand msrp price_promo_text promotext_code promotext_type promotext_value is_preowned model_id on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}sku stock_status moredetails{description __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}... on GiftCardProduct{allow_open_amount open_amount_min open_amount_max giftcard_type is_redeemable lifetime allow_message message_max_length giftcard_amounts{value_id website_id website_value attribute_id value __typename}__typename}meta_title@include(if%3A$onServer)meta_keyword@include(if%3A$onServer)meta_description@include(if%3A$onServer)canonical_url@include(if%3A$onServer)}__typename}}&operationName=productDetail&variables={%22urlKey%22%3A%22raymond-weil-watch-7730-stc-jhdx1%22,%22onServer%22%3Atrue}' (UTF-8) -> 'graphql@query=query productDetail($urlKey%3AString,$onServer%3ABoolean!){productDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A{url_key%3A{eq%3A$urlKey}}){items{__typename id sku name name_wout_brand on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority is_preowned brand_name brand_url manufacturer url_key stock_status out_of_stock_template out_of_stock_template_text price_promo_text promotext_code promotext_type promotext_value shipping_availability is_shipping_free_message shipping_question_mark_note model_id image{label url __typename}upc_code item_variation media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}breadcrumbs{path categories{name url_key __typename}__typename}review_details{review_summary review_count __typename}rating_configurations{rating_attributes __typename}short_description{html __typename}description{html __typename}moredetails{description more_details{group_id group_label group_attributes{attribute_id attribute_label attribute_value __typename}__typename}__typename}msrp price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}categories{breadcrumbs{category_id category_name __typename}__typename}... on GroupedProduct{items{qty position product{id sku stock_status name brand_name name_wout_brand manufacturer manufacturer_text is_shipping_free_message shipping_availability url_key is_preowned preowned_item_condition preowned_item_condition_text preowned_box preowned_papers preowned_papers_year preowned_condition_description on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority shipping_question_mark_note model_id msrp price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}moredetails{description __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}... on ConfigurableProduct{configurable_options{attribute_code attribute_id id label values{default_label label store_label use_default_value value_index swatch_data{type value... on ImageSwatchData{thumbnail __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}variants{attributes{code value_index label __typename}product{id brand_name brand_url brand_size manufacturer shipping_availability is_shipping_free_message shipping_question_mark_note name_wout_brand msrp price_promo_text promotext_code promotext_type promotext_value is_preowned model_id on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority price_range{minimum_price{regular_price{value currency __typename}final_price{value currency __typename}price_promo_text msrp_price{value currency __typename}discount_on_msrp{amount_off percent_off __typename}discount{amount_off percent_off __typename}__typename}__typename}media_gallery{... on ProductImage{label role url sizes{image_id url __typename}url_nocache __typename}__typename}sku stock_status moredetails{description __typename}__typename}__typename}__typename}... on GiftCardProduct{allow_open_amount open_amount_min open_amount_max giftcard_type is_redeemable lifetime allow_message message_max_length giftcard_amounts{value_id website_id website_value attribute_id value __typename}__typename}meta_title@include(if%3A$onServer)meta_keyword@include(if%3A$onServer)meta_description@include(if%3A$onServer)canonical_url@include(if%3A$onServer)}__typename}}&operationName=productDetail&variables={%22urlKey%22%3A%22raymond-weil-watch-7730-stc-jhdx1%22,%22onServer%22%3Atrue}' (CP1252)
    The name is too long, 3814 chars total.
    Trying to shorten...
    New name is graphql@query=query productDetail($urlKey%3AString,$onServer%3ABoolean!){productDetail%3Aproducts(filter%3A{url_key%3A{eq%3A$urlKey}}){items{__typename id sku name name_wout_brand on_hand_priority_text on_hand_priority is_preowned brand_na.

    Found www.jomashop.com in host_name_addresses_map (0000000007b14a20)
    Connecting to www.jomashop.com (www.jomashop.com)|104.20.213.46|:443... seconds 0,00, connected.
    Created socket 3.
    Releasing 0x0000000007b14a20 (new refcount 1).
    Initiating SSL handshake.
    Handshake successful; connected socket 3 to SSL handle 0x000000001094c020
    certificate:
      subject: CN=jomashop.com,O=Jomashop Inc.,L=Brooklyn,ST=New York,C=US,serialNumber=1493412,businessCategory=Private Organization,jurisdictionST=New York,jurisdictionC=US
      issuer:  CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/,O=GoDaddy.com\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US
    X509 certificate successfully verified and matches host www.jomashop.com
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure of way in Windows, but it seems Linux can do that: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/wget-for-long-url-and-dependent-files-745108/ Try with Linux if you have. Or you can share it here to see if I can do something for you

Comment: Unless you provide a concrete error message from, say, `Invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell, sensible help is not possible.

Comment: Try to [use POST instead of GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682393/how-to-download-a-file-with-a-very-long-url).

Comment: @Saeed I shared one link - if would be helpful, if you could try to download it.

Comment: @DanielB I tried to use WGet - and posted an error description from it.

Comment: @Evgeniy the link opens with no problem for me in my Google Chrome in Windows. I'm not sure if that's why my chrome is updated. But you can share all links and I can download them and provide you a shorter link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example it is now clear what the problem is:

> Cannot write to '…' (Bad file descriptor).
> converted '<very long url>' (UTF-8)
> Converted file name '<many a character>' (CP1252)
> The name is too long, 3814 chars total.

In this case, the solution is very easy: Just specify a target file name that is *not* too long:

```
wget -O my-result.json "<very long url>"
```

With GraphQL you can *maybe* also POST the query instead of specifying it in the URL. This would work around any URL length problems.